# Integrar ViewControllers de un pod a un proyecto propio

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Estoy desarrollando una app iOS con Swift, la cuál utiliza pods creados por mí mismo también con Swift. Estos pods tienen varios ViewControllers definidos, tanto con la parte lógica como con las UI. Mi duda es: cómo debo hacer para que desde el proyecto de la app, e integrando los pods con Cocoapods, pueda indicar cual ViewController quiero que se ejecute primero (siendo este VC de uno de los pods agregados al proyecto general), y como debo hacer también si necesito hacer transiciones entre un VC de un pod a un VC de otro pod distinto

NO utilizo Storyboards, las UI están hechas de forma programada con código con UIKit según el VC

Comment: Utilizas storyboards?

Answer (score 0):

tienes que buscar el SceneDelegate.swift y agregar algo similar al codigo inferior para presentar el VC que deseas.

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {


        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

        self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout))
        window?.rootViewController = navController



    }
```

en este caso he creado un HomeViewController que es un UICollectionViewController, pero usted podria colocar en su lugar la clase del controllador que desea que se muestre al iniciar la app, si su proyecto es antiguo posiblemente tenga que hacer el cambio en el appDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

En el `AppDelegate` instancias el `ViewController` que deseas que se ejecute:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = ViewController()//El nombre del ViewController de tu Pod
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```